# How to stop message states the link has expired and was sending a new link using docusign

Tags: docusignapi

How to stop message states the link has expired and was sending a new link when links being sent via email are expiring after a day or so using DocuSign?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this feature is to improve security. Links can be shared in various ways, but DocuSign wants to ensure you are still the person who originally received the link by sending you a new email to the same account that was used to send the original link (based on the recipient in the envelope).
If the envelope is completed, it cannot be modified. Which means the only option to stop would be to void it.
If the envelope is still in flight, you can "correct" it and remove the recipient that has this link.
If you are the sender you can use [recipient authentication](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-implementing-docusign-recipient-authentication) (multi-factor auth) where users have to supply a code for example and that prevents the link from expiring.